# Async Action Creator - Jest and Axios - Timeout - Async callback was not invoked

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-redux, jestjs, axios

I am writing tests for my async action creators but I am getting a timeout error when my test runs. I tried

- Moxios
- Increasing jest timeout
- MockAdapter

I am currently trying Moxios again.

myTest (edited to reflect changes):

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import moxios from 'moxios'
import * as actions from './actions'
import mockData from './mockData'

const middleware = [thunk]
const mockStore = configMockStore(middleware)

describe('action tests: ', () => {
 beforeEach(function() {
  moxios.install()
 }

 afterEach(function() {
  moxios.uninstall()
 }

 it('should get data', async done => {
  moxios.stubRequest('/data/*', { status: 201, response: mockData })

  const expectedActions = [{ type: actions.dataActions.RECEIVED_DATA }]

  const store = mockStore({ data: [] })

  await store.dispatch(actions.getData()).then(() => { 
   expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
  })
  done();
 }, 10000)
})
```

The error I am getting is: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 10000ms timeout...`

By looking at my code and coverage, I can see that the promise does not get used, as the .then() portion doesn't get executed based on my code coverage. So am I doing something wrong with my test case? I have looked around on other people's implementation of Axios with jest but I am always getting this timeout error.

Code being tested:

```
export cosnt getData= () => {
 return dispatch => {
  dispatch(isFetching())
  return dataApi.retrieveData().then(res => {
   dispatch(updateData(res))
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code you are testing so we can see what is going wrong

Comment: @RedBaron, I added the code being tested. Should I add the API function as well? It is a standard GET for axios

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 things may cause this error:

1. The url wildcard doesn't work well in `stubRequest`, you should specify part or full of the uri(add hostname for external api endpoint).

   e.g. `moxios.stubRequest('/data/*', { status: 201, response: mockData })`
2. `resolves` should not be there, as `.then` above has got the promises back.
   after update it should be:

   `expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)`

I have a sandbox similar to this test case:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-redux-thunk-49696

You could refer to file `redux.spec.js`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have changed the ```stubRequest``` url to resemble your example and removed the ```.resolves``` call after the ```expect``` but I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Do you use Axios to hit the endpoint in 'retrieveData' function,  because moxios can only mock Axios request. And try to use the full uri in stubRequest, if the wild card does work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up switching to fetch as everything I tried with Axios wasn't working.